# Populating a spinner via a query

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I have a somewhat strange/annoying problem where I am populating the spinner dropdown elements by querying the necessary string elements from Firestore. The querying part is not the problem. It is the populating part. The spinner (actually it is the MaterialBetterSpinner) is in a fragment. And I have to wait a second or two to open the spinner. If I do not then the spinner does not work. I tried moving the query to the onCreate and then to the onStart overrides of the fragment to no avail. What are my options here without ruining the UX by perhaps disabling the spinner using a handler for a couple of seconds?

Here is are the methods:

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        Query myRestaurants = firebaseFirestore.collection("Restaurant_Data").whereArrayContains("users", getUser());
        myRestaurants.get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                Restaurant restaurant = documentSnapshot.toObject(Restaurant.class);
                spinnerList.add(restaurant.getRestaurantAddress());
                restaurantArrayList.add(restaurant);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception for spinner: " + e.getMessage());
        });
    }
```

And this method is called from the onCreateView in the fragment:

```
private void getRestaurants() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(restaurantContext, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, spinnerList);
        materialDesignSpinner = restaurantView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_spinner);
        materialDesignSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making an asynchronous call to get the "Restaurant_Data". Thus, the spinner only gets populated after the data is gotten.

You could try to get over this (as you suggested) by disabling the spinner until the data is retrieved successfully. Another workaround would be to prefetch the data (if you know for sure that this activity is going to be opened). For example, you could prefetch the data in the preceding activity and store it in a static variable.

Comment: I hid the spinner immediately after defining it and then after the array was populated I display it. Now it works like a charm and I don't have to depend on a passive runnable and even worse succumb to null objects.